# Call componentWillReceiveProps() after state is getting updated from reducer React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 components

1] Parent
2] child

I am passing parent components action to child to get called on change of dropdown list.

Parent components method is calling stores's function (ajax call) and updating state variable.
After updating state I want to perform few operations in componentWillReceiveProps() but It is not going inside componentWillReceiveProps ().

Below is code in parent component -

1 ] Parent

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this._setTrackToParams(props)
    debugger;
    let liveVideoList = this.state.liveVideoList
    if(props.liveRaceVideos != null && _.isEmpty(this.state.liveVideoList)) {
        console.log('live race video if')
        this.state.liveVideoList.push(props.liveRaceVideos)
        this.setState(this.state)
    } else if(props.liveRaceVideos != null && this.selectedKey) {
        console.log('live race video else')
        this.state.liveVideoList[this.selectedKey] = props.liveRaceVideos
        this.setState(this.state)
    }
    console.log("bye")
}

  renderChild() {
    let selectValue = !this.selectedKey ? this.props.params.trackCode : this.selectedKey
    if(this.state.liveVideoList) {
        return _.map(this.state.liveVideoList,(value , key) => {
             if(key < 3) {
                return (
                    <LiveVideoPanel ref = "liveVideoPanel" key = {key} currentTracks = {this.props.currentTracks} liveVideos = {value} selectedValue = {selectValue} onChange = {this._toggleVideos} onChangeTrackList = {this.onChangeTrackList.bind(this)} videoCount = {key}/>
                )
             }
        })
    }
}


    onChangeTrackList(id, key) {
    if(id) {
        this.selectKey = key
        this.props.fetchLiveRaceVideo(id)
    }
}
```

So i am calling this.onChangeTrackList() function on change of dropdown list.
and this function internally calling this.props.fetchLiveRaceVideo(id) action.
I am getting "link" from this ajax call. and that link is getting updated in state.

After state updation i want to call componentWillReceiveProps() , but this is not getting called.

Comment: Did you verify that your action `this.props.fetchLiveRaceVideo` is being invoked? Have you verified that the action type you expect is being dispatched by this action? Also, have you checked what state is being returned by the reducer handling the dispatched action type?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that componentWillReceiveProps isn't being called because componentWillMount is being called instead. I would put in a console.log and see if that is the case.

From the docs:

> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may update. Calling this.setState generally doesn't trigger componentWillReceiveProps.